# Anyone know about pagination with post method in laravel?

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel-5, laravel-pagination

Anyone here know about pagination with post method in laravel? Here's my code my pagination didn't work properly can anybody help me with this? It shows first page data when i move to next page it shows the empty render...I tried it through ajax with post method coz i need fiter data with pagination...

**Blade:**

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
    <div id="html_code" class="col-sm-6 col-lg-12" style="margin-bottom:20px; background-color:#047137">
        <table>
            <tr><th>Name</th>
                <th>Email</th></tr>
            @foreach($get_data as $data)
                <tr><td>{{$data->name}}</td>
                    <td>{{$data->email}}</td></tr>
            @endforeach
        </table>
    </div>                              
    <div>
        {!!$get_data->links()!!}
    </div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(document).on('click', '.pagination a', function(event){
 event.preventDefault();
 var page = $(this).attr('href').split('page=')[1];
 fetch_data(page);
 });

function fetch_data(page)
 {$.ajax({
   url:"/pagination/fetch_data?page="+page,
   success:function(data)
   {$('#html_code').html(data);}
  });
 } 
});
</script>                 
@endsection
```

**Controller:**

```
public function users(Request $request)
    {
        $category = $request->category;
        $get_data = User::where('category',$category)->paginate(20);
        return view('data',compact('get_data'));
    }

    function fetch_data(Request $request)
    {
        $category = $request->category;
     if($request->ajax())
     {
        $get_data = User::where('category',$category)->paginate(20);
        return view('data',compact('get_data'))->render();
     }
    }
```

**Routes:**

```
 Route::match(['get', 'post'], 'monthly_report', ['uses'=>'HomeController@users']);

    Route::get('pagination/fetch_data', 'HomeController@fetch_data');
```

Comment: You are using `category` parameter in your condition whereas you are passing your `page` value.

Comment: Muhammad Shareyar but i need both parameters for my function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add this code in return view code:

```
'users' => $users->appends(Input::except('page'))
```

Answer (score 0):

With `post` data in Laravel, you need to send `csrfToken` as a part of your request.

Since I don't have access to whole code for debugging. You can look at the following link.

https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-57-ajax-pagination-exampleexample.html

Comment: Thanks dexter. I go through from this link before but in this link he is doing it with get method simply wherease, i am trying to do it with post method by passing arguments to controller.

Comment: @DanishZahoor did you find a solution otherwise I can update the answer.